# Limit of quadratic functions - what is the name of this and why does it work?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

While calculating the limit of quadratic functions, the 
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} = \frac{(x - a)\cdot something}{(x-a) \cdot something}$$
formula is commonly used (well, I know stating it like this is probably not particularly precise, but I hope you get the idea). For example:
$$\lim_{x \to 4}\frac{x^2 -9x + 20}{x^2 - x -12} = \lim_{x \to 4}\frac{(x-4)(x-5)}{(x-4)(x+3)}$$

My question is: what is the name of this formula and why does it work?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not a formula...you factor both polynomials, and when taking $x\to a$ as a limit, you can assume $x\neq a$, which allows you to cancel a term that might be zero when $x=a$ from the numerator and denominator.

Comment: It works because so long as $x\ne 4$ then $\frac {x-5}{x+3}$ and $\frac {(x-4)(x-5)}{(x-4)(x+3)}$ will be equal and will have the same limits.  The only times $\frac {x-5}{x+3}$ and $\frac {(x-4)(x-5)}{(x-4)(x+3)}$  are different (and they *are* very different) is when $x = 4$.  But the who point of $\lim_{x\to 4}$ is that we considering when $x$ is *close* to $4$ but that $x$ is *NOT* $4$.

Comment: If there are any common factors in numerator and denominator and you can spot them easily then it is always better to get rid of them by canceling and thus simplify the fraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has a name, I don't know it. But, yes, it is true that if $a$ is a root of both polynomials $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, that is, if can write $p(x)$ as $(x-a)p^\star(x)$ and $q(x)=(x-a)q^\star(x)$, where $p^\star(x)$ and $q^\star(x)$ are also poynomials, then, indeed,$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p^\star(x)}{q^\star(x)},$$assuming that the later limit exists. This is so because\begin{align}\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\cancel{(x-a)}p^\star(x)}{\cancel{(x-a)}q^\star(x)}\\&=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{p^\star(x)}{q^\star(x)}.\end{align}